# AngularJS: how to display a new view inside the same page as modal?

Tags: angularjs

I am quite new to AngularJS.
It looks like AngularJS can handle multi view application with ng-view.

My question is: how can I stay on the same page but make the ng-view display as inline modal box ?!

(It looks like ng-view replaces totally the original view)

[image]
Structure of the site is

```
<div id="mainContainer">
   <div id="loginBoxModule"></div>
   <div id="usersBoxModule"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: checkout Angular UI project: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: This isn't the normal use-case for `ng-view`, as `ng-view` is designed to be the bulk of the application, with the only things falling outside of it (normally) being navigation and chrome, etc. Are you going to have your whole site running inside the modal window, and never outside of it?

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout Ui.Router -> https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

What it basically does is the following.

You create a partial that you want to load and in the index.html you can put something like:

```
<body>
    <a ui-sref="list">Show List</a>

    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

When clicking the link the partial list.html will load into the ui-view. So it will only reload the ui-view and not the whole page.

Comment: ok: I guess you use a route and partial for that. But why not use ng-view ?

Comment: Hmm, i forgot why, they are basically the same but there was something ui-view did for me what the ng-view couldn't..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ng-include instead of ng-view. ng-view has a very specific behavior as it's hardly linked to the ui-router as Mike was mentioning.
With ng-include you can have a set of tabs at the top of the page and when you click on a tab, you just load another template (which has 1 parent div and 1 ng-controller on that div for instance).

Not sure what's your real use case though.